# Stop all running activity and admob ads

Tags: java, android, android-activity, admob, ads

i'm trying to add my apk in play store  but support team  reject my app because "violates our interfering with apps and third-party ads policy, Remove any interstitial ads that appear after the user has exited the app, or after the user has pressed the back button to exit the app."

in interstitial  ads  i  repeat it  each 40 seconde after closeded  without  checking if user still  navigate the same activity  that way

this my code :

```
    // Start Interstitial Ads
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            //.addTestDevice("TEST")
            .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    new Timer().schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 30000);


    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    //.addTestDevice("TEST")
                    .build();
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
            new Timer().schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 40000);
        }
    });

    // End Interstitial Ads
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing an interstitial ad based on a hard timer isn't the best way to go (not to mention that forty seconds between ads is very short!). Interstitials should be displayed when there's a natural break in the action, such as when a user completes a task, or moves from one part of your app to another. Switching to this kind of flow will solve the problem the Play store review pointed out and help you maintain your user base in the long run.

For more info on the best ways to use interstitials, try these resources:

- [AdMob's Interstitial Guidance](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6066980)
- [Mobile Ads Garage Episode #5, Interstitial Best Practices](https://youtu.be/r2RgFD3Apyo?list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKX0pUJV3uqp6N3NeHwHh0c)